# angular 1.2 directive scope issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When creating a directive with **isolate scope**, but **no template** in the directive, but with some dom inside the directive, the dom inside the directive can not bind to the scope of the directive.

```
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    {{hehe}}
    <hr/>
    <div test-directive="hello" >
      Directive Data: 
      <div>{{test}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller("testCtrl",['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.hehe = "test from controller";

}])
.directive("testDirective",function(){
  return{
    scope: {
      "testDirective": "="
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

      $scope.test = "test from directive";

    }]
  };
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/AgeGigIR/3/edit)

In the demo, there are two angular lib versions, 1.1.5 and 1.2.4, and one of them is commented.

The code works with 1.1.5 but not with 1.2.4.

Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: Thanks Fabrício for help me edit the question. make this question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a change in 1.2.x. The isolate scope is truly isolate and you can only really bind to it from a template **inside** your directive (defined through `template:` or `templateUrl:`).

The template in your HTML will never inherit the scope of your directive.

The point of isolate scopes is to isolate the internal implementation of your directive from the outer template. The old behavior dind't fully isolate the directive and made things more coupled.

It is not recommended to use isolate scope unless you are using an internal template in the directive. When not using `template:` or `templateUrl:`  you should just use `scope: true` or just no scope at all.